# How to fetch Redirected URL or it's content via Requests Library?

Tags: python, python-requests

I am using `request` to fetch data. on USPS.COM the tracking [URL](https://tools.usps.com/go/TrackConfirmAction!input.action?tRef=qt&tLc=1&tLabels=9405510200830149879122) is redirecting permanently(301) hence can't see desired page. The URL work's perfectly on Browser.

**Update:**

Added the Real URL for clarification/debugging

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Redirection and History - Requests documentation](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history):

> Requests will automatically perform location redirection for all verbs
>   except HEAD.

So, you don't need to worry about redirection.

---

The problem is that *USPS.COM* checks `User-Agent` header and returns different result according to the header value. You need to specify the header to get the same result with the browser.

For example:

```
import requests

url = 'http://.....'
r = requests.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
assert 'Delivered' in r.content
```

Comment: I am already using this UA: `headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.102 Safari/537.36'}`

Comment: Just checked my `connect` method did accept `headers` parameter but did pass in `get` method. Thanks!!